# Does the single sign-on allow user permanantly logged in with the SkyDrive in windows phone app?(Description Inside)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I'm working on windows phone 8 app, I've seen the concept of single sin-on to the Microsoft account; My doubt is, does the single sign-on process stores the user's session for lifetime for that particular app. . .

for example consider the Native SkyDrive app in Windows 8 it gets the username and password only once. It won't ask the user again if the system or phone or app restarts.

or

please say me how login works on the native SkyDrive app, because it asks the username and password only once.

Comment: Does it keep you permanantly logged in of course it doesn't.  It stores the permission information( not the password or username ) in order to get a new session when the old one expires.

Comment: how r they doing in the native app.

Comment: You ask if it kept you permanantly logged in it does.  It simply keeps the information it needs to automatically authorize itself.